# Neo4j Cypher NULL values and descending sorting

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an auditing filed for all of my entities:

```
createDate
updateDate
```

I always initialize `createDate` during the entity creation but `updateDate` can contain `NULL` until the first update.

I have to implement sorting feature over these fields.

With `createDate` everything works fine but with `updateDate` I have issues.

In case of a mixed set of NULLs and Dates in `updateDate` during the descending sort, I have the NULLs first and this is not the something I'm expecting here.

I understand that according to the Neo4j documentation, this is an expecting behavior - [When sorting the result set, null will always come at the end of the result set for ascending sorting, and first when doing descending sort.](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/order-by/#order-by-ordering-null)  but I don't know right now how to implement the proper sorting from the user perspective where the user will see the latest updated documents at the top of the list. Some time ago I have even created GitHub issue for this feature https://github.com/opencypher/openCypher/issues/238

One workaround I can see here - is to populate also `updateDate` together with `createDate` during the entity creation but I really hate this solution.

Are there any other solutions in order to properly implement this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use the createDate as the updateDate when updateDate IS NULL:

```
MATCH (n:Node)
RETURN n
ORDER BY coalesce(n.updateDate, n.createDate) DESC
```

Comment: I think this is pretty the same approach to simply initialize updateDate together with createDate during the node instantiation that I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I assumed you were trying to avoid the extra storage.  I really don't see much benefit otherwise.

Comment: but your solution works! So the additional question... will it significantly affect the performance of the query or no?

Comment: I don't believe it's much overhead to coalesce these columns at query time.

An exception to that would be if you're relying on an index for performant scans of updateDate.  If that poses a problem, I think I'd just set the updateDate at creation time.  It's minimal storage for significant ease-of-use gains.

Also, I'd say that if you switch to an epoch timestamp (integer) you'll get storage and performance benefits all around (if performance is of concern).

You could then ORDER BY -updateDate ASC (note the negative updateDate) to get descending data with nulls at the end.  HTH.

Comment: thank, I'd love to switch to the epoch timestamp but I don't know how to do it with SDN4

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the [coalesce() function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-coalesce). It will return the first non-null value in the list of expressions passed to it.

```
MATCH (n:Node)
RETURN n
ORDER BY coalesce(n.updateDate, 0) DESC
```

**EDIT:**

From comments:

> on the database level it is something like this: "updateDate":
>   "2017-09-07T22:27:11.012Z". On the SDN4 level it is a Java -
>   java.util.Date type

In this case you can change the 0 by a date representing an Start-Of-Time constant (like "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z").

```
MATCH (n:Node)
RETURN n
ORDER BY coalesce(n.updateDate, "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately it's doesn't work :(

Comment: @alexanoid Which error are you getting with this query?

Comment: on the database level it is something like this: "updateDate": "2017-09-07T22:27:11.012Z". On the SDN4 level it is a Java - java.util.Date type

Comment: @alexanoid Well, in this case you can change the `0` by a date representing an Start-Of-Time constant (like `"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"`). But I believe that a best approach is store dates as milliseconds since epoch.

Comment: I use the SDN4 automatic mappings between Java types and Neo4j and I don't know right now what is the correct way to do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153969/discussion-between-bruno-peres-and-alexanoid).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider storing your ISO 8601 timestamp strings as (millisecond) integers instead. That could make most queries that involve datetime manipulations more efficient (or even possible), and would also use up less DB space compared to the equivalent string.

One way to do that conversion is to use the APOC function [apoc.date.parse](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_conversion_between_formatted_dates_and_timestamps). For example, this converts `2017-09-07T22:27:11.012Z` to an integer (in millisecond units):

```
apoc.date.parse('2017-09-07T22:27:11.012Z', 'ms', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
```

With this change to your data model, you could also initialize `updateDate` to 0 at node creation time. This would allow you to avoid having to use `COALESCE(n.updateDate, 0)` for sorting purposes (as suggested by @Bruno Peres),
 and the `0` value would serve as an indication that the node was never updated.
 (But the drawback would be that all nodes would have an `updateDate` property, even the ones that were never updated.)